# what is the equivalent functions of glArrayElement()& glTexGeni() in openGL ES

Tags: iphone

can anyone please tell me what are the equivalent functions for  glArrayElement()& glTexGeni() in openGL ES..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalents for these two functions.

OpenGL|ES is a stripped down and leaner version of OpenGL, so some stuff has been left out.

glArrayElement is not required as the whole glBegin / glEnd rendering mode has been removed from GL|ES. glArrayElement does not make sense without the glBegin/glEnd anymore. Since you'll have to rewrite the rendering code to use glDrawArrays/glDrawElements you will not miss it.

glTexGen has been removed as well. If you use a later version of GL|ES, you can emulate all the functionality using vertex shaders. If you're stuck with early GL|ES (1.0 or 1.1) you have to emulate it in software (e.g. calculate the texture coordinates on your own and pass them to gl via glTexCoordPointer).